# Connection refused when trying to dockerize my redis cache along with flask server

Tags: python, docker, flask, redis

I have an existing web application that uses flask and redisCache for backend. My goal is to dockerize it and eventually deploy on aws lightsail but I am struggling to understand the correct approach given that I already have a populated cache that I wish to maintain.

I've managed to create a docker container for the code I've shown below but when I run it, I am unable to access any data from my redis instance - I am returned `redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to 0.0.0.0:6379. Connection refused` despite having an active redis server.

What is the correct way to dockerize my redis cache along with my flask server? Do they both belong in the same container or different ones? I've attached the server and docker files for reference.

Cheers!

```
# Set base image (host OS)
FROM python:3.9-slim


# By default, listen on port 5000
EXPOSE 5001/tcp

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /server


# Copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install any dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY flask-server.py .
COPY gpt.py .
COPY article_feed.py .
COPY credentials.py .


ENV PYTHONPATH /Back_end



# Specify the command to run on container start
CMD [ "python", "./flask-server.py" ]
```

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  redis:
    image: "redis:latest"
    command: ["redis-server", "--bind", "redis", "--port", "6379"]
```

```
cache = Cache(config={"CACHE_TYPE": "RedisCache",
                      "CACHE_REDIS_HOST": "0.0.0.0",
                      "CACHE_REDIS_PORT": 6379,
                      "CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT": -1})


def create_app():

    app = Flask(__name__)
    cache.init_app(app)

    @app.route('/Politics')
    def post_politics():
        print("politics routed")
        if cache.get('Politics') is None:
            cache.set('Politics', getArticleFeed(politics, 4))
        return cache.get("Politics")

    @app.route('/Business')
    def post_Business():
        if cache.get('Business') is None:
            cache.set('Business', getArticleFeed(business, 4))
        return cache.get("Business")

    @app.route('/Health')
    def post_Health():
        if cache.get('Health') is None:
            cache.set('Health', getArticleFeed(health, 4))
        return cache.get("Health")

    @app.route('/Entertainment')
    def post_Entertainment():
        if cache.get('Entertainment') is None:
            cache.set('Entertainment', getArticleFeed(
                arts_and_entertainment, 4))
        return cache.get("Entertainment")

    @app.route('/Science')
    def post_Science():
        if cache.get('Science') is None:
            cache.set('Science', getArticleFeed(science, 4))
        return cache.get("Science")

    @app.route('/Technology')
    def post_Technology():
        if cache.get('Technology') is None:
            cache.set('Technology', getArticleFeed(technology, 4))
        return cache.get("Technology")

    @app.route('/Environment')
    def post_Environment():
        if cache.get('Environment') is None:
            cache.set('Environment', getArticleFeed(environment, 4))
        return cache.get("Environment")

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=5001)


create_app()
```

Comment: Your question is really well put together, but for your sake of finding the right audience to answer it you should really change the heading of the post to something like `Connection refused when trying to dockerize my redis cache along with my flask server` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a redis image in docker-compose.yml file, you must have the redis_host set to "redis" and not '0.0.0.0'

The name 'redis' is the name of the services of image 'redis:latest'